# python 'concatenate' requires extra parentheses

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm trying to concatenate 3 lists.  When I try to use concatenate, like so, I get an error (TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer):

```
import numpy as np

a = [1]
b = [2]
c = [3]
z = np.concatenate(a, b, c)
```

But if I put "extra" parentheses, it works like so:

```
z = np.concatenate((a, b, c))
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what library you are using (`concatenate` is not a built-in python 3.x function). However, I'll explain what I think is going on.

When you call `concatenate(a, b, c)`, the function `concatenate` is sent three parameters: `a`, `b`, and `c`. `concatenate` then performs some logic that is (presumably) not the desired behavior.

When you call `concatenate((a, b, c))`, a tuple (effectively a list that cannot be changed) is created with a value of `(a, b, c)`, which is evaluated to `([1], [2], [3])`. Then this tuple is passed to the `concatenate` function. The following code is actually equivalent to your second code snippet:

```py
a = [1]
b = [2]
c = [3]
y = (a, b, c)  # This evaluates to ([1], [2], [3]).
z = concatenate(y)
```

I hope I've explained this clearly enough. Here's an article that explains tuples in more depth, if I haven't: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp

EDIT: Thanks for including the library. Here's the code for what you're probably trying to do:

```py
import numpy as np
a = [1]
b = [2]
c = [3]
z = np.array(a + b + c)  # Lists can be concatenated using the `+` operator. Then, to make a numpy array, just call the constructor
```

Comment: As to which library, it is numpy (hence 'np.concatenate').